# How can I use a custom domain alias with Gmail?

Tags: gmail, smtp

It used to be possible to configure your Gmail inbox to send email as `you@yourdomain.com` by simply redirecting that email address to your inbox, and then sending through a confirmation email.

But since a [recent change](http://googlesystem.blogspot.jp/2014/08/external-addresses-no-longer-use-gmail.html), that's not possible anymore and you now need to set up a full SMTP server.

My question is, what is the recommended technique/service to use to regain the previous functionality? Use a third-party SMTP provider? If so, which one?

Comment: mailjet.com and mailgun.com are two possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google suggests using the SMTP servers of @yourdomain.com.

If you are able to log in / read and send mail from there you should be able to use this process:

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/send-mail-from-another-address-without.html

1. Log into your domain and find the SMTP server information
2. Add that to the Google Settings.

Note: all of my Google accounts have the old settings so I am not able to fully test this feature.  Please let us know what you find if this is not enough information.